# C - Proper reuse of code / methods between files

Tags: c, module, linker

I'm a C beginner with average Java Skills and I'm not sure how to reuse C code between files properly.

Let's say I have two files / modules: `server.c` and `client.c`

They are not linked (with GCC) and should run in separate processes.

There are two methods in `server.c` that I want to use in `client.c`. Those methods use global, static (const) variables in the same module. Basically I want the same functionally as when I would copy them into the other file.

Small example:

`server.c`

```
static const char *progname = "server";

static int sockfd = -1;
static int connfd = -1;

static void free_resources(void)
{
    if (sockfd >= 0) {
        (void) close(sockfd);
    }

    if (connfd >= 0) {
        (void) close(connfd);
    }
}
```

`client.c`

```
static const char *progname = "client";

static int sockfd = -1;
static int connfd = -1;

// I want to use free_resources here
```

If I want to use the same method in `client.c`, what would be the right way to do it?

If I create a separate `util.c` / `util.h` module with the method, how do I access the global variables? Should I pass them as arguments every time? Remove static?

In Java I would probably create a class and pass the (reference to the) global variables once. Is there a similar approach in C?

Comment: "how do I access the global variables". Who is "I" in this context?

Comment: @kaylum The utility module (?) util.c that I would include in server.c and client.c.

Comment: But those variables would be presumably in util.c as well. So any function in that file would be able to access them. What did you intend instead? If you need access to those variables outside the file then you would have one of the APIs in that file return them.

Comment: as long as the variables don't need to be shared between client.c and server.c you can statically link util.c with each of the other modules, and use the globals as extern in each of the other modules.  Don't declare them as static in util.c.

Comment: Look up "extern variables" in your C tutorial.

Comment: @kaylum The variables in server.c and client.c don't have the same values (see *progname). Just the same name. I added a code snippet for client.c.

Comment: @bruceg Barmar Thanks, I'll look that up. I got the 1988 K&R book from the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Java I would probably create a class...

The equivalent in C is to create a structure, and pass a pointer to the structure to any functions that need access to the variables. The structure declaration should be in utils.h, e.g.

```
typedef struct
{
    char *progname;
    int sockfd;
    int connfd;
}
Info;

void free_resources( Info *info );
```

Create and initialize the structure in server.c and client.c, and then pass the address to the common functions, e.g.

```
Info server_info = { "server", -1, -1 };

int main( void )
{
    // ...

    free_resources( &server_info );
}
```

Then the code in utils.c looks like this.  (Note that you can't use the `static` keyword, since the function must be callable from outside utils.c)

```
void free_resources( Info *info )
{
    if (info->sockfd >= 0) {
        (void) close(info->sockfd);
    }

    if (info->connfd >= 0) {
        (void) close(info->connfd);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How does that compare to using external variables like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412265/c-proper-reuse-of-code-methods-between-files#comment68074914_40412265 mentioned?

Comment: @MWin123  There are two main differences. 1) Using the structure reduces name space pollution, e.g. the name `sockfd` in the structure will never conflict with a local variable called `sockfd`, because the former is in the structure namespace, not in the global namespace. 2) You could have multiple instances of the structure, in exactly the same way that you can have multiple instances of a class. You probably don't need that now, but you never know in the future.